# yo version check fails while behind proxy

Tags: npm, yeoman, spfx

I am trying to setup my SharePoint framework environment and Yeoman is required. My PC (Win10 home edition) is sitting behind company proxy server and I have setup related config (I setup both http-proxy and http_proxy because I don't know which one is right)

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm config ls -l |findstr prox
http-proxy = "http://proxy2:8080"
http_proxy = "http://proxy2:8080"
https-proxy = "http://proxy2:8080/"
https_proxy = "http://proxy2:8080"
proxy = "http://proxy2:8080/"
; https-proxy = null (overridden)
noproxy = null
; proxy = null (overridden)
```

However it is still fail for version check:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npx yo doctor
.......
× yo version
{ RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.21.35:443
    at ClientRequest.req.once.err (C:\Users\mpllui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\got\index.js:73:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.21.35:443',
  host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
  hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/yo' }
√ npm version
```

I tried to understand the issue discussion here (https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/589). It looks like the bug is fixed in 2018 already. I checked my yo version is latest:

```
C:\Windows\system32>yo --version
3.1.0
```

How can I solve it? Or indeed version check is not important because I have latest version already?

Answer (score 0):

HAve a look at this issue. https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/589

Looks like Yo is using variable GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY. (The very last comment)